# Как скопировать текст длинным нажатием на TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Как сделать чтобы по длинному нажатию на `TextView` копировалось содержимое этого `TextView` в буфер обмена? Нашёл способ с `ClipboardManager` но он уже устарел, есть ли какая-то альтернатива?

Comment: подвесить на длинное нажатие копирование в буфер, не? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Вариант 1: включить стандартный копипаст атрибутом `android:textIsSelectable` или методом `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true)`. Вариант 2: повесить лонгкликлистенер и самому поместить текст в буфер обмена: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste#Copying

Comment: ClipboardManager живее всех живых, читайте оф док https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener {
        val clipboard = textView.context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager?
        val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Order Number", textView.text.toString())
        clipboard?.setPrimaryClip(clip)
        true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txv_menu_7.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("",txv_menu_7.getText().toString());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.string.link_copied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
return true;
});
```